# MBP'13 (Late 2011) Win7 (BootCamp) + iMac'27 (Mid 2011) as an external display?

Tags: macbook-pro, imac, bootcamp, windows, thunderbolt-display

Is it possible to use iMac'27 (Mid 2011, MacOS) as an external/target mode display for the MBP'13 (Late 2011) running Windows 7 in Bootcamp?

I'm using thunderbolt cable.

It works perfectly fine if MBP is booted into Mac, but Win7 can't seem to detect external display. Command + F2 on the iMac does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You have to reboot the machine into boot camp with the display already connected.

See apples KB article here: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3924 (bottom of the article)

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work even if I connect display in Mac and then reboot into Bootcamp. Isn't this KB article applies only to 2009/2010 iMacs anyways?

Comment: Are you using a thunderbolt cable or mini displayport?

Comment: Thunderbolt cable.

Comment: Hmm that's the cable its supposed to work with according to the apple kb. It won't work if there is a minidisplay adaptor.